# Enforce minimum version of AWS CLI in a bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am writing bash scripts that make heavy use of the AWS cli, and I need to ensure a minimum version is installed. Is there a better way to do that than to parse the output of `aws --version`?

Comment: Depending on how you are installing it in the first place, use your package manager's functions? Here are [instructions for apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578460/specify-apt-get-a-minimum-version-to-be-installed), [yum](https://superuser.com/questions/330661/installing-a-specific-package-version-with-yum), and [apk](https://superuser.com/questions/1055060/how-to-install-a-specific-package-version-in-alpine), here's

Comment: That doesn't help me. The script will be used by others who may have installed the cli in any number of ways.

Comment: Then no, probably not.